# JavaScript: is it possible to access private variables (i.e. which have been hidden inside a closure)?

Tags: javascript, closures

I have implemented an object as a closure in JavaScript, some of the methods are public, some other are private:

```
var MyObject = (function(){

    function _hiddenMethod() {
        /* Do something fancy here, such as reading data 
        from an external source and storing it in 
        _hiddenVariable2 */
    } 

    var _hiddenVariable1 = 3;
    var _hiddenVariable2 = undefined;

    return {
        publicMethod: function() {
            _hiddenMethod();
            return _hiddenVariable1;
        };
    };

})();
```

Is there a way in which a (skilled) user could possibly read the content of `_hiddenVariable2`? I assume it knows its existence by having read the JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way I know of but it might depend on the javascript engine.

Also keep in mind, that anyone can debug javascript and note whenever _hiddenVariable2 is set in the closure (write something like _hiddenVariable2 = 5 inside the _hiddenMethod, try developer tools for chrome and insert a breakpoint into the _hiddenMethod, and you will be able to see when _hiddenVariable2 is set).

So a skilled user can know the current value of it if hes debugging the code in V8 for example.

Answer (score -1):

Declare it as `_hiddenVariable2 = undefined;` instead of `var _hiddenVariable2 = undefined;`
It will be available to any other module in your code

Comment: Wow, you haven't used the word *global* but that's what it is `window._hiddenVariable2` **global variable**!

Comment: This doesn't address the question at all

Comment: yes! you are right. If you do not use var, it becomes a global variable

Comment: Thank you for the insight! It didn't answer the question, but I didn't know either.